# Bootable DVD won't boot on my laptop

Tags: boot, bios, dvd, backtrack

So I burned BackTrack 5 R3 on a DVD and hoped to use it on my new laptop but some Problems occured. I made a bootable DVD and the laptop was setup to first check the CD/DVD and then the hard drive. But it wouldn't boot. I then went into the boot options and there I couldn't find my DVD to boot from. At first I thought I didn't burn the CD correctly but I tried it on my fathers PC and it worked normaly... Now I am really stuck and I dont know what to do.
If it helps, my laptop is an Acer Aspire E 15.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Did you disable secure boot?**

Secure boot might prevent any non-certified, e.g. non-Windows systems, to boot from your PC.

Comment: No Problem :) Can you explain maybe how to do it?

Comment: First go to your BIOS-Menu and look for the secure boot entry, switch it from enabled to disabled. Some systems require you to set a supervisor password first in order to grant full access to all those features. Please note down this password as you might lose access to your BIOS if you forget it. In some cases secure boot can only be turned off from a hidden page in the BIOS-menu.

Comment: Ok, I have made a password, disabled the secure boot but it still wont boot the DVD...I press also F12 but still nothing. Whats strange, I switched to Legacy settings in the boot options and the DVD booted, but when I start the text mode I get a black screen and I was waiting and waiting and nothing happened

Comment: Hm yeah that sounds kind of familiar. Possible workaround: If you have an USB device and the iso-file you could try to make it a bootable device. Use Rufus on Windows or usb-creator on Linux (or dd (command line interface utility).

Comment: @HeatTheIce Were you able to boot BackTrack or as karel suggested Kali or do you still need some assistance?

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple causes.

Sounds like you checked the first thing you should (BIOS settings).

Try booting a CD (maybe Memtest 86+ since that is small and fast to download).

It could be that your system doesn't like the type of DVD.  There are multiple types.  DVD+R is apparently slightly superior (maybe discs last longer?  Or slightly higher capacity?) but DVD-R is a bit older and may be slightly more compatible.  If that works, trying a disc from a different manufacturer may help.  If this resolves the problem, I would say the "fault"/"blame" is in the DVD drive (not being very accepting).

It may be that BackTrack just doesn't work so well on a system, although I'm not inclined to think that is the most likely cause.

Comment: Thank for the replay, but it seems like it's the Problem that Alex posred.

Answer (score 0):

BackTrack Linux is no longer being maintained. At the official BackTrack Linux webpage, you are referred to its successor [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/). To avoid unnecessary problems, you should install the latest version of Kali Linux instead of BackTrack. To avoid the risk of problems arising from a badly burnt DVD, you would be better off installing Kali Linux from a live USB flash drive instead of from a DVD. You will need a USB flash drive, 4GB or larger.

#### Creating a bootable Kali Linux USB Drive on Windows

<sup>(instructions from the [official Kali Linux website](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install))</sup>

> 1. Download the [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) utility.
> 2. Plug your USB drive into an available USB port on your Windows PC, note which drive designator (e.g. `F:\`) it uses once it mounts, and launch the Win32 Disk Imager program you downloaded.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Choose the Kali Linux ISO file to be imaged and verify that the USB drive to be overwritten is the correct one. If you make a mistake and select the Windows drive instead of the USB drive, you will overwrite your Windows operating system, so make sure to verify that the USB drive to be overwritten is the correct one! Click the *Write* button.
> 4. Once the imaging is complete, safely eject the USB drive from the Windows computer. You can now use the USB device to boot into Kali Linux.